# confusing about simple ros c++ code

Tags: ros, c++, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a simple question about c++ pointer. This is the main.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "joint_trajectory_action_node");
  ros::NodeHandle node;//("~");
  JointTrajectoryExecuter jte(node);

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

And this is part of the constructor of JointTrajectoryExecuter

```
public:
  JointTrajectoryExecuter(ros::NodeHandle &n) :
    node_(n),
    action_server_(node_, "joint_trajectory_action",
                   boost::bind(&JointTrajectoryExecuter::goalCB, this, _1),
                   boost::bind(&JointTrajectoryExecuter::cancelCB, this, _1),
                   false),
    has_active_goal_(false)
```

node_ is defined as ros::NodeHandle node_;

I don't understand "node_(n)".

Can anyone give me any hint?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64107/confusing-about-simple-ros-c++-code/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-05-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mortonjt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4408/mortonjt/) on 2013-05-31**:
I think you may be referring to a [initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look at the `ros::NodeHandle` [documentation](http://ros.org/rosdoclite/fuerte/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#aa109e12a4f4d393a023e819b9b65d887), you can find a copy constructor that matches that signature:

```
ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle(const NodeHandle &rhs)
```

Essentially, this creates a new `NodeHandle` instance that inherits a copy of all the parameters from the original `NodeHandle`.  In the `JointTrajectoryExecuter` class you reference, this creates a local `NodeHandle` variable within the class that is a a copy of the `NodeHandle` created when the node is first initialized.  The class can then use this local copy for handling actions, messages, etc.

In general, this isn't necessary, as all `NodeHandle` objects in a given node point to the same underlying object.  But this version does allow the new `NodeHandle` to inherit the namespace of the original `NodeHandle`, if one was specified.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2